# smtplib in python is not rfc 2822 compliant

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtplib

As stated in the [SMTP](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)

That smtplib is not RFC complaint.Can we know any other alternative library to send email using the library which is RFC 2822 Compliant in Python.

Comment: Where does it state ot is not compliant?

Comment: You can see the link over the SMTP Text in the question ...

Comment: It does not mention RFC 2822 at all so does not say it is not compliant